# How to find which number parent a list item appears in with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu system that indicated the active item with a class of "selected". Menu items are categorized into groups contained in a div. I'm trying to determine which group number the selected item is in. for example, in the code below it's in the second div group, so I'm trying to return a value of "2". Is this possible?

```
<div class="nav_group">
   <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav_group">
   <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="selected"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have done ?

Comment: Close your `<li>` tags and add the `=` sign for the *selected* `class` and you'll have a valid HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieve the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) of the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `div.nav_group` containing the `li.selected`:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var index = $('li.selected').closest('.nav_group').index();
    console.log(index); // outputs 1 (as 0 is the first)

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suvpv3vu/1/)

Comment: would suggest using `closest` since `parents` travels all the way up the dom tree and creates a collection of all `div` that are ancestors.

Comment: @charlietfl: Right, I just read the documentation and I agree that `.closest()` is better to use.